# SDWebImage clear cache with tag for a set of image

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

i'm using the amazing `SDWebImage` project, to refresh the download of an image i use this:

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] removeImageForKey:img_key fromDisk:YES];
```

and works, but i want to know if it's possible to give a tag for some images, so i can clear the cache for a set of images and not for only one, it's that possible?

Comment: I wanted to remove only 1 image, so I found my answer within your question :P thank you.. +1

Answer (score 3):

`SDImageCache` has a init method named `- (id)initWithNamespace:(NSString *)ns;`

you can use it to init a new instance instead of `sharedImageCache`, thus you can `clearDisk`, `clearMemory` without affecting others.

Answer (score 0):

as you can see `SDImageCache` is using `memCache` ( `NSCache` ). You cannot remove defined set of images by tags for removing. You can clean memory/clear disk using this methods from.

```
- (void)clearMemory;
- (void)clearDisk;
```

I suggest you to create own nscache to define keys for images that you would like to remove. Then you can easily change it, or extend `SDImageCache`.

Cheers